# Can I use Apple Universal Links with HTTP server?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have not been able to confirm this anywhere, so maybe someone here can.
I know that when targeting iOS 9+ and using HTTPS one can implement Universal Links with plaintext app-site-association-file.

I also know, that when supporting Handof/Shared Web Credentials, the file needs to be signed.

What I'm interested in is whether Universal Links will work with signed file avaiable via HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those wondering - no you cannot. Even when using a signed file (which was a requirement for Handoff and Shared Web Credentials in iOS 8), the connection still needed to be accesible via HTTPS.

Reference from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/SharedWebCredentialsRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014989) :

> The file must meet the following requirements:
>
> 1. The file must be hosted on an https:// site with a valid certificate
>      (for example, Safari must not issue a certificate warning when viewing
>      the site).
> 2. The file must not use any redirects.
> 3. The file must have the MIME type application/pkcs7-mime.
> 4. The file must be CMS signed by a valid TLS certificate.